# laravel Error: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, sql, laravel, jquery-select2

I have gone through every solution I could find over youtube, stakoverflow and other websites. I am using Select2 to add multiple roles but I a consistently getting the same error.

```html
<select id="role" name="role_id[]" multiple='multiple' 
        class="form-control js-example-basic-multiple">
    @foreach($roles as $role)
        <option value="{{$role->id}}">{{$role->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

DD function is showing perfect result but after that it shows error.

[image]It works perfectly untill I add [] with the name="role_id[]". 
form action is as under.

```js
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'=> 'required|string|max:225',
        'status'=> 'required',
        'role_id'=> 'required',
        'email'=> 'required|string|email|max:225|unique:users',
        'password'=> 'required|string|min:6|confirmed'
    ]);

    $password = Hash::make($request->password);
    // dd($request->all());

    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->status = $request->status;
    $user->role_id = $request->role_id;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->remember_token;
    $user->save();
    // $user->roles()->sync($request->roles, false);
    return back()->with('message', 'User added successfully!!');
}
```

If I validate for integer  'role_id'=> 'required|integer', it shows error [image]

Migration is as under

```js
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedInteger('role_id')->default(1);
            $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Change it to `'role_id.*'=> 'required',` and role_id is collection of array you should run that with loop and then insert in `users role` table since user have more than one role you need to keep them in another table like user_roles

Comment: error is here `$user->role_id = $request->role_id;` in this line you are assigning array (`$request->role_id`) to single variable. So, you should first create array and then used foreach loop on `$request->role_id` to assign value to array

Comment: I have another error in validation as well. If I use 'role_id'=> 'required|integer', instead of  'role_id'=> 'required', I get error "The role id is not integer".

Comment: @AliAnwar whats the error?? You should include the actual error message in your question

Comment: error is "The role id is not integer" when I validate for Integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have pivot table for roles than you dont need role_id column in your users table

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [
    'name'=> 'required|string|max:225',
    'status'=> 'required',
    'role_id'=> 'required|array',
    'email'=> 'required|string|email|max:225|unique:users',
    'password'=> 'required|string|min:6|confirmed'
]);

$password = Hash::make($request->password);
// dd($request->all());

$user = new User;
$user->name = $request->name;
$user->status = $request->status;
$user->email = $request->email;
$user->password = $password;
$user->remember_token;
$user->save();

foreach($request->input('role_id') as $role)
{
   $user->assign($role);
}
// $user->roles()->sync($request->roles, false);
return back()->with('message', 'User added successfully!!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question but I am getting error again with this code.

Comment: Please check this 33:00 to 33:35 in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNUYaLWdR04&t=232s

Comment: The error is SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'role_id' at row 1

Comment: That is because you have set length in your database column `role_id` that is exceeding when you are selecting more than one roles in your dropdown. so make it larger as `varchar(256)`

Comment: my data type is integer

Comment: I think you need to make pivot table for roles that will add rows as per `user_id` and `role_id`. By having integer in users table it will not work as you have multiple roles you will need to make it `varchar` as it will contain an array so array wont be able to store in an integer datatype

Comment: @AliAnwar Check this link https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-56-user-roles-and-permissions-acl-using-spatie-tutorialexample.html

Comment: I have pivot table. Problem is somewhere in view that I could not find.

Comment: if you have pivot table than you dont need column `role_id` in users table remove that and make foreach loop through all role ids and add it in your pivot table after creating user record

Comment: Ok. Let me check

Comment: Why is it not validating for integer?

Comment: Because it will be an array so it will not validate as integer

Comment: use `required|array` to validate as an array

Comment: I am following ur suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

`$request->role_id` is array so you can't store array to database directly so you can use following,

```
  $user->role_id = json_encode($request->role_id);
```

Later you can use `json_decode` function to get array of role_id.

Comment: Thanks for answering to my question. I am getting another error with this code.

Comment: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '["2","3"]' for column 'role_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `status`, `role_id`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Admin, 0, ["2","3"], admin@xyz.com, $2y$10$DEzjq.XtHPL06FnbtPTa9Oht0Bm5k9eJQT1dh6.A/5TBmVqMGi3yy, 2018-11-29 06:22:48, 2018-11-29 06:22:48))

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

`$request->role_id` is an array. not a single data.

**Suggestion:**

Here two things

You allocating multiple rules with an user

You should not store your rules in users table

You should do that like this:

create another table to store users role

and store user rules separately

Example:

```
      $user = new User;
      $user->name = $request->name;
      $user->status = $request->status;
      $user->email = $request->email;
      $user->password = $password;
      $user->remember_token;
      $user->save();

      $roleAssigns = [];
      foreach($request->role_id as $role){
          $roleAssigns[] = [
              'role_id' => $role,
              'user_id' => $user->id
          ]
      }
      //UserRole is the model of user_roles table
      UserRole::insert($roleAssigns);
```

Comment: You have pointed out the problem rightly. I tried your code but again I am getting syntax error. I have another error in validation as well. If I use 'role_id'=> 'required|integer', instead of 'role_id'=> 'required', I get error "The role id is not integer". I have seen many people using many to many relationships adding data the same way.

Comment: if controller want integer type role_id then you should pass integer from view. its the view issue.

Comment: I am following the process as Alex is following in many to many relations in his youtube tutorial. I have also seen in many tutorials for the many to many relationships. But in my case its not working.   Please check this 33:00 to 33:35 in this tutorial youtube.com/watch?v=BNUYaLWdR04&t=232s –

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "echo" an array, that is the error.

you will need to collect the lines in an array, and then return that array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output an array for your `.js` code, you may use

[@json($array)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade)

since Laravel 5.5