# Laravel Array to string conversion error while updating database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to update a totcosty field in the User table but it is throwing this error everytime and it is not updating the field

this is the function for execution:

```
public static function cost(){
  $user = User::find($user_id);
  $total = Helper::totcost();
  // dd($tot_amt);
  $user->totcosty = $total;
  $user->save(); 
}
```

Comment: What does `Helper::totcost()` return?

Comment: Whats the error ?

Comment: it is showing array to string and it is not updating the table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532112/laravel-error-array-to-string-conversion maybe this gets you on the right path?

Comment: Helper::cost is a public class Helper where I return the value I want to insert in table.

Comment: As per the error, you are trying to insert array into the field.And the solution of storing the array is you can serialize the array data.

Comment: Actually I tried to put the position number still not working

Comment: You will have to answer the questions if you expect help - just to repeat what others already asked: What does the method `totcost` return (maybe add the code to the question?),  what is the exact error, and just a hint: Why would you get the user id via auth user only to select the user? `auth()->user()` already returns your user. Maybe your error is within the `totcost` method.

Comment: totcost return a decimal value that To use to update the table

Comment: The error is as I described in the title array to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array to string means you are sending an array to the database but db will not accept it you have to explode() the array before sending it to db...
Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to store an array in some table field, then better declare it as a JSON field. For this, your DB should have support for JSON type columns.

[See here how to do this.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

Once this is done, you can save arrays in that column, you can assign an array value to the model property and laravel will convert it to JSON while saving and also it will be converted to array while retrieving.